# iOS: Where to change the name of my app AFTER it is already in the app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have read other posts saying that this is possible, that all I need to do is submit an update.  But, in the process of submitting the update, where do I enter the new name?

When adding a new app version, I see no place to enter the new name. I don't just want the springboard name to change, but also the the name that appears in the app store and search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to change your app name is to submit again your app with changed name in the Info.plist. For the name displayed on theAppStore it's done on iTunes Connect.

Comment: There we go. Finally see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The name that will appear in the App store is entered in the Metadata form on an app updates "Add Version" page.  The name that appears under the icon is entered in the app's Info.plist.