# iOS: Where to change the name of my hybrid app AFTER it is already in the app store?

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

There is a similar question [iOS: Where to change the name of my app AFTER it is already in the app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235434/ios-where-to-change-the-name-of-my-app-after-it-is-already-in-the-app-store) but it's not for hybrid.

Is it in the config.xml or elsewhere? We're using Phonegap for our builds.

I'm stuck here, can you help?

Cheers,
andy

Comment: Same answer holds good here as well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10235571/366346. Open Xcode and edit info plist.

Comment: Cool - do I do that **after** I get the build from Phonegap?

Comment: Is it as simple as changing this?
  `<name>My App Name</name>` in config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Write your app name in bundle display name.

Answer (score 0):

In the `config.xml`, change the name in `<name>App Name</name>`